# Getting list properties types using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

tI want get list models properties type using reflection. I have a model list and each of list property's type should required for me

```
public class Params
{
public class AnalitikButceKodlariListesiOutput
        {
            public string KOD { get; set; }
            public string KOD_01 { get; set; }
            public string KOD_02 { get; set; }
            public string KOD_03 { get; set; }
            public string KOD_04 { get; set; }
            public string BUTCE_ADI { get; set; }
            public double YIL { get; set; }
        }

public class AnalitikButceKodlariListesiYilOutput : AnalitikButceKodlariListesiOutput
        {
        }
}
```

---

```
List<WebParameters.Params.AnalitikButceKodlariListesiYilOutput> list = new List<WebParameters.Params.AnalitikButceKodlariListesiYilOutput>();

WebParameters.Params.AnalitikButceKodlariListesiYilOutput item = new WebParameters.Params.AnalitikButceKodlariListesiYilOutput()
            {
                KOD = "a",
                KOD_01 = "",
                KOD_02 = "d",
                KOD_03 = "c",
                KOD_04 = "d",
                BUTCE_ADI = "e",
                YIL = 2015
            };
```

I try this but it wasn't success.

```
foreach (var pObject in list)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in pObject.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                       var type = pObject.GetType().GetProperty(item2.Name).GetType().Name;
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better that you call `GetProperty` providing some binding flags:

```
pObject.GetType().GetProperty(item2.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetType().Name;
```

BTW, I suspect you're looking to get property type and `pObject.GetType()` will give you the type of `PropertyInfo` rather than the declared property type. Use `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` instead:

```
string propertyTypeName = pObject.GetType()
         .GetProperty(item2.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
         .PropertyType
         .Name;
```

Comment: Thanks Matias  for your answer